# Why Janus Graph is not called a framework while Apache TInkerPop is?

Tags: database, frameworks, tinkerpop, janusgraph

It may be a naive question but I am new to this field?

Why Janus Graph is not called a framework (according to definition on first document page) while Apache TinkerPop is?

Comment: It's a database. HBase or Cassandra (the backing systems) have their own frameworks.  A framework is generally just a library

Comment: @cricket_007 But Janus Graph is built on top of Apache TinkerPop.

Comment: So? It's not a framework because it's a database. You cannot run JanusGraph within other applications as an imported library

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On their own, the core Apache TinkerPop interfaces really don't do anything - you couldn't build an application with them. All they do is provide a generic layer over any graph database and any graph processing model. As a result, we refer to TinkerPop as a "framework".

JanusGraph and other TinkerPop-enabled graph systems are "implementations" of the TinkerPop framework. They are not "built on top" so as to be extensions to the generic interfaces that it exposes as a framework. They plug into the framework so that your use of those interfaces (i.e. Gremlin) are backed by something that gets/stores data.

Comment: Could you explain little bit more on ' All they do is provide a generic layer over any graph database(this is not meant for Janus graph) and any graph processing model.'

Comment: Not sure how else I can say it. TinkerPop is an abstraction layer to graph databases/processors, much like JDBC is an abstraction to connect to different relational databases. As a developer you build your application through the abstraction layer - for TinkerPop that would mean, writing Gremlin and for JDBC that would mean SQL.

Comment: In both cases, by using an abstraction layer you are able to switch between implementations of that abstraction - for TinkerPop that would mean, that the same Gremlin you write for Neo4j will also generally work for JanusGraph which will also generally work for DSE Graph, etc. (any TinkerPop compliant system) and for JDBC it would mean that the same SQL you write for MS SQL Server would generally work for Oracle which would generally work for any JDBC compliant database.

Comment: You couldn't write an application with just JDBC, right? It's a "framework" of sorts (using that term a bit loosely) - you have to choose a database to go with it. Same thing with TinkerPop. I'm not sure why you wrote "(this is not meant for Janus graph)" as an amendment to my quote. It is quite meant for JanusGraph...JanusGraph is a graph database and TinkerPop provides an generic abstraction layer over it.

Comment: That said, JanusGraph is a native implementation of TinkerPop - it uses TinkerPop interfaces as its own. Some TinkerPop enabled graphs systems do that and some do not. Perhaps that is the source of your confusion.